# Issue with Magic Bitboards

Tags: engines, programming, bitboard

I have a implemented a similar version to the example given on [the chess programming wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Looking_for_Magics) by Tord Romstad.

I just changed the random generation and stored the magics in an array. I even kept the old count_1s and didn't use any modern instructions.

If I test the magics on a bitboard it always give wrong results. I assume there is some problem with the transform function.

Here is the code :

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <stdlib.h>

std::array<uint64_t, 64> ROOK_MASK, BISHOP_MASK;
std::array<uint64_t, 64> ROOK_MAGIC, BISHOP_MAGIC;
std::array<std::array<uint64_t, 4096>, 64> ROOK_MAGIC_LOOKUP, BISHOP_MAGIC_LOOKUP;

std::random_device rd;
std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> dist(0, UINT64_MAX);

void printBitboard(const uint64_t& bb)
{
    uint64_t mask = 0;
    for (int rank = 7; rank >= 0; rank--) {
        for (int file = 0; file < 8; file++) {
            int square = rank * 8 + file;
            mask = 1ULL << square;
            if (bb & mask) {
                std::cout << '1';
            }
            else {
                std::cout << '0';
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "______________" << std::endl << std::endl;
}

uint64_t random_uint64_fewbits()
{
    return dist(rd) & dist(rd) & dist(rd);
}


int count_1s(uint64_t b) {
    int r;
    for (r = 0; b; r++, b &= b - 1);
    return r;
}

const int BitTable[64] = {
  63, 30, 3, 32, 25, 41, 22, 33, 15, 50, 42, 13, 11, 53, 19, 34, 61, 29, 2,
  51, 21, 43, 45, 10, 18, 47, 1, 54, 9, 57, 0, 35, 62, 31, 40, 4, 49, 5, 52,
  26, 60, 6, 23, 44, 46, 27, 56, 16, 7, 39, 48, 24, 59, 14, 12, 55, 38, 28,
  58, 20, 37, 17, 36, 8
};

int pop_1st_bit(uint64_t* bb) {
    uint64_t b = *bb ^ (*bb - 1);
    unsigned int fold = (unsigned)((b & 0xffffffff) ^ (b >> 32));
    *bb &= (*bb - 1);
    return BitTable[(fold * 0x783a9b23) >> 26];
}

uint64_t index_to_uint64(int index, int bits, uint64_t m) {
    int i, j;
    uint64_t result = 0ULL;
    for (i = 0; i < bits; i++) {
        j = pop_1st_bit(&m);
        if (index & (1 << i)) result |= (1ULL << j);
    }
    return result;
}

uint64_t rmask(int sq) {
    uint64_t result = 0ULL;
    int rk = sq / 8, fl = sq % 8, r, f;
    for (r = rk + 1; r <= 6; r++) result |= (1ULL << (fl + r * 8));
    for (r = rk - 1; r >= 1; r--) result |= (1ULL << (fl + r * 8));
    for (f = fl + 1; f <= 6; f++) result |= (1ULL << (f + rk * 8));
    for (f = fl - 1; f >= 1; f--) result |= (1ULL << (f + rk * 8));
    return result;
}

uint64_t bmask(int sq) {
    uint64_t result = 0ULL;
    int rk = sq / 8, fl = sq % 8, r, f;
    for (r = rk + 1, f = fl + 1; r <= 6 && f <= 6; r++, f++) result |= (1ULL << (f + r * 8));
    for (r = rk + 1, f = fl - 1; r <= 6 && f >= 1; r++, f--) result |= (1ULL << (f + r * 8));
    for (r = rk - 1, f = fl + 1; r >= 1 && f <= 6; r--, f++) result |= (1ULL << (f + r * 8));
    for (r = rk - 1, f = fl - 1; r >= 1 && f >= 1; r--, f--) result |= (1ULL << (f + r * 8));
    return result;
}

uint64_t ratt(int sq, uint64_t block) {
    uint64_t result = 0ULL;
    int rk = sq / 8, fl = sq % 8, r, f;
    for (r = rk + 1; r <= 7; r++) {
        result |= (1ULL << (fl + r * 8));
        if (block & (1ULL << (fl + r * 8))) break;
    }
    for (r = rk - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
        result |= (1ULL << (fl + r * 8));
        if (block & (1ULL << (fl + r * 8))) break;
    }
    for (f = fl + 1; f <= 7; f++) {
        result |= (1ULL << (f + rk * 8));
        if (block & (1ULL << (f + rk * 8))) break;
    }
    for (f = fl - 1; f >= 0; f--) {
        result |= (1ULL << (f + rk * 8));
        if (block & (1ULL << (f + rk * 8))) break;
    }
    return result;
}

uint64_t batt(int sq, uint64_t block) {
    uint64_t result = 0ULL;
    int rk = sq / 8, fl = sq % 8, r, f;
    for (r = rk + 1, f = fl + 1; r <= 7 && f <= 7; r++, f++) {
        result |= (1ULL << (f + r * 8));
        if (block & (1ULL << (f + r * 8))) break;
    }
    for (r = rk + 1, f = fl - 1; r <= 7 && f >= 0; r++, f--) {
        result |= (1ULL << (f + r * 8));
        if (block & (1ULL << (f + r * 8))) break;
    }
    for (r = rk - 1, f = fl + 1; r >= 0 && f <= 7; r--, f++) {
        result |= (1ULL << (f + r * 8));
        if (block & (1ULL << (f + r * 8))) break;
    }
    for (r = rk - 1, f = fl - 1; r >= 0 && f >= 0; r--, f--) {
        result |= (1ULL << (f + r * 8));
        if (block & (1ULL << (f + r * 8))) break;
    }
    return result;
}


int transform(uint64_t b, uint64_t magic, int bits) {
    return (int)((b * magic) >> (64 - bits));
}

bool find_magic(int sq, int m, bool bishop) {
    uint64_t mask, b[4096], a[4096], used[4096], magic;
    int i, j, k, n;
    bool fail = false;

    mask = bishop ? bmask(sq) : rmask(sq);
    n = count_1s(mask);

    for (i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
        b[i] = index_to_uint64(i, n, mask);
        a[i] = bishop ? batt(sq, b[i]) : ratt(sq, b[i]);
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 100000000; k++) {
        fail = false;
        magic = random_uint64_fewbits();
        if (count_1s((mask * magic) & 0xFF00000000000000ULL) < 6) continue;
        for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++) used[i] = 0ULL;
        for (i = 0;!fail && i < (1 << n); i++) {
            j = transform(b[i], magic, m);
            if (used[j] == 0ULL) used[j] = a[i];
            else if (used[j] != a[i]) fail = true;
        }
        if (!fail)
        {
            if (bishop)
            {
                BISHOP_MAGIC[sq] = magic;
                std::memcpy(BISHOP_MAGIC_LOOKUP[sq].data(), used, sizeof(used));
            }
            else
            {
                ROOK_MAGIC[sq] = magic;
                std::memcpy(ROOK_MAGIC_LOOKUP[sq].data(), used, sizeof(used));
            }
            
            return true;
        }
            
    }
    return false;
}

int RBits[64] = {
  12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12,
  11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
  11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
  11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
  11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
  11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
  11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
  12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12
};

int BBits[64] = {
  6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6,
  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
  5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5,
  5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5,
  5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5,
  5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5,
  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
  6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6
};

uint64_t getRookMoves(const uint64_t& allBlockers, const int& square)
{
    std::cout << "All Blockers" << std::endl;
    printBitboard(allBlockers);

    uint64_t maskedBlocker = ROOK_MASK[square] & allBlockers & (~(0b1ULL << square));

    std::cout << "Masked Blocker" << std::endl;
    printBitboard(maskedBlocker);

    int index = transform(maskedBlocker,ROOK_MASK[square], RBits[square]);

    uint64_t attacks = ROOK_MAGIC_LOOKUP[square][index];

    std::cout << "Attacks from Magics" << std::endl;
    printBitboard(attacks);

    std::cout << "Correct Attacks" << std::endl;
    printBitboard(ratt(square, maskedBlocker));
    return attacks;
}



void main()
{
    //fill MASKS
    for (size_t square = 0; square < 64; square++)
    {
        ROOK_MASK[square] = rmask(square);

        BISHOP_MASK[square] = bmask(square);
    }

    //find magics for each square (bishop + rook)
    for (size_t square = 0; square < 64; square++)
    {
        bool r = find_magic(square, RBits[square],false);
        bool b = find_magic(square, BBits[square], true);
        if (!(r && b))
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR FINDING MAGICS"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "FINISHED FINDING MAGICS" << std::endl;

    //Test for bitboard 0xa07c04000154bc28 on square 0 / a1
    getRookMoves(0xa07c04000154bc28, 0);
}
```

The only thing changed from the original is the `random_uint64_fewbits` and the `find_magic` function.

In the `getRookMoves` i am testing my results. I test wether the Magic-Generation produces the same output as the `ratt` function. Example :

```
Attacks from Magics
00000000
00000000
00000000
10000000
10000000
10000000
10000000
01000000

Correct Attacks
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
10000000
10000000
10000000
01110000
```

They don't match so there is some error, I was not able to find.

If someone has some other resource for finding and testing magic bitboard, please share them with me.

Comment: Two comments on the code itself. First, `std::random_device` is best used to seed a PRNG, and not as a general purpose generator. See the comment in the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device). Second, nothing in this code needs the extra study that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigation, if found out that the issue was in the `GetRookMoves` function. The issue was that i was using the `ROOK_MASK` as parameter and not the `ROOK_MAGIC` array.

```
uint64_t getRookMoves(const uint64_t& allBlockers, const int& square)
{
    std::cout << "All Blockers" << std::endl;
    printBitboard(allBlockers);

    uint64_t maskedBlocker = ROOK_MASK[square] & allBlockers & (~(0b1ULL << square));

    std::cout << "Masked Blocker" << std::endl;
    printBitboard(maskedBlocker);

    int index = transform(maskedBlocker,ROOK_MAGIC[square], RBits[square]);

    uint64_t attacks = ROOK_MAGIC_LOOKUP[square][index];

    std::cout << "Attacks from Magics" << std::endl;
    printBitboard(attacks);

    std::cout << "Correct Attacks" << std::endl;
    printBitboard(ratt(square, maskedBlocker));
    return attacks;
}
```

This is the new `getRookMoves` function.
I leave the question online beacuse, i think it can be a good example how to use magics.